# Getting the nodequeue id from the nodequeue name?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to get the nodequeue qid from the nodequeue  name.

Suppose I have a node queue with the name of "Slider". I want a function so that I pass it the name of the nodequeue and It returns the qid or sqid of that nodequeue.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an API function for it but writing your own should be fairly straightforward:

```
function nodequeue_load_queue_by_name($name) {
  $query = db_select('nodequeue_queue', 'nq')
    ->fields('nq', array('qid'))
    ->fields('nsq', array('sqid'))
    ->condition('nq.name', $name);

  $query->join('nodequeue_subqueue', 'nsq', 'nsq.qid = nq.qid');

  $result = $query->execute()->fetchObject();

  // Decide whether you want to use $result->qid or $result->sqid based on your 
  // business logic, then return it.
  $return_val = a_function($result);

  return $return_val;
}
```

That comes straight from memory so excuse any small mistakes, but I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function of the same name as in the excepted answer included in current versions of the nodequeue module.

```
$queue = nodequeue_load_queue_by_name($name);
```

It returns the queue definition, or an empty array if no queue was found with the given machine name. So the id would be found at:

```
$queue->qid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the table existance.

```
$table = db_table_exists('nodequeue_queue');<br>
  $table1 = db_table_exists('nodequeue_subqueue');<br>

  if ($table1 && $table) {<br>
    $query = db_select('nodequeue_queue', 'nq')<br>
      ->fields('nq', array('qid'))<br>
      ->fields('nsq', array('sqid'))<br>
      ->condition('nq.name', $queue_name);<br>

    $query->join('nodequeue_subqueue', 'nsq', 'nsq.qid = nq.qid');

    $result = $query->execute()->fetchObject();
  }
```